# why does the CSS translate3d use a left hand coordinate system

Tags: css

I was reading the web uses a right hand coordinate system where z-axis positive is into your screen
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSSOM_View/Coordinate_systems

However, when i was playing around with
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d
a positive z translation moves the cube towards you. This means the coordinate system used by CSS is left-handed.

Why does CSS use a left-hand coordinate system for 3D translations, unless this is a bug?

Comment: it was defined that way: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-transforms-2/#transform-rendering *adding a Z axis perpendicular to the plane of the screen, that increases towards the viewer.* ... you probably need to find all the discussion made before creating the Spec to find the reason of such decision

Comment: as a side note, z-index work the same way so it's not only related to transform